# Custom Control for Painter application to show different erasers

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, binding

I am creating paint like application using WPF. Now i need to create control which can be used to display eraser but it should be like adobe photoshop's eraser control where three different types of eraser  small , medium and large are in one control , it have overflow mechanism like toolbar .

I need to create custom control (may be custom button) which will have little arrow which will allow me to see types of eraser and allows me selection. for reference check eraser control in ONE note application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered templating the drop down menu button?

Here are a couple of examples to get you started:

http://anothersplitbutton.codeplex.com/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/10/25/split-button-in-wpf.aspx